# Obj-C, how to save / add a unique list of date ranges using NSUserDefaults?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsuserdefaults

I need to save two date (a date range) to NSUserDefaults.

The range needs to be unique in the list of dates stored ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save `NSDate` objects to the user defaults. Do something like this:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:firstDate forKey:@"StartDate"];
[defaults setObject:secondDate forKey:@"EndDate"];
```

Comment: How do i keep the list unique, so that the same two dates don't get saved twice.

Comment: @Jules: That'll have to be done in code, but the simple check would be comparing the start date of the second range to see if it is >= the start date of the first range and <= the end date of the first range.

Comment: so you mean I'd have to read all the values from NSUserDefaults, evaluate them and save in necessary ?

Comment: @Jules: Yeah. `NSUserDefaults` won't do any uniqueness validation for you. You'll have to handle that logic yourself.

Answer (score 0):

That's based on [this question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805219/obj-c-how-to-store-retreive-several-date-ranges-and-evaluate-it-for-use-based), right? The DateRange class provided as my answer to that question implements `-isEqual:` and `-hash` methods, so you can use DateRange objects in an NSSet. NSSet guarantees uniqueness of its members based on `-isEqual:` (see NSSet's documentation for details). All you need is to put a number of DateRange objects into an NSMutableSet, encode the set with NSKeyedArchiver and store the resulting NSData object in NSUserDefaults.