# How to check if date (from date picker) is between two other dates ? objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdateformatter, uidatepicker

i'm trying to get date from UIDatePicker (MM-dd format) and to check if its in the range of two other dates;

i have tried it in so many different ways and i think my mind has gone to far :)
can someone help me do it as simple as it should be?

this is my last try code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM-dd"];
NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:birthdateSelector.date];
NSDate *birthdate = [dateFormat dateFromString:theDate];

NSString *Capricorn_Start = @"12-22" ;
NSString *Capricorn_End = @"01-19" ;

if ([birthdate laterDate:[dateFormat dateFromString:Capricorn_End]] && [birthdate earlierDate:[dateFormat dateFromString:Capricorn_Start]]){

    NSLog(@"im capricorn");
}
```

Thanks,
Amir.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Check if an NSDate occurs between two other NSDates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072848/how-to-check-if-an-nsdate-occurs-between-two-other-nsdates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have *dateA*, *dateB* and *dateC*, and you want to check if *dateA* < *dateB* < *dateC*, you can get the difference between *dateA-dateB* and *dateB-dateC* which will give you *diffX* and *diffY*. If *diffX* sign is equal than *diffY* sign, it will mean that *dateB* is between *A* and *C*.

Or, in other words, your code would look like this:

```
NSTimeInterval diffX = [dateB timeIntervalSinceDate:dateA];
NSTimeInterval diffY = [dateC timeIntervalSinceDate:dateB];

if (signbit(diffX) == signbit(diffY))
{
    // dateB is in-between dateA and dateC
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Methods `laterDate` and `earlierDate` return an `NSDate`.

You should use instead [compare:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/compare%3a) and check the return value.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a year (the same one for both) and then get the time from 1970 for instance and then do your comparisons.