# How can i check my current time is between starttime and endtime?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Check if an NSDate occurs between two other NSDates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072848/how-to-check-if-an-nsdate-occurs-between-two-other-nsdates)

In my application i have got the time in string like this,

starttime(string) : 10:00 AM

endtime(string) : 12:22 PM

My current time is 11.55 AM

How can i check my current time is between starttime and endtime?

Comment: This will probably be the easiest.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807370/how-to-check-if-date-from-date-picker-is-between-two-other-dates-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

Use this way :

First convert your string to `NSDate` using `NSDateFormatter`.

Then directly compare those two dates with currentDate which is always `[NSDate date]`.

You may use these two instance method of NSDate.

`isGreaterThan:` and `isLessThan:`

Or,

```
if (! (([currentDate compare:startDate]==NSOrderedAscending) && ([currentDate compare:endDate]==NSOrderedDescending)){
    NSLog(@"Valid date");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First try to remove AM and PM

Like its PM then add +12 in that time frame.

Then check weather the current time's digits which is before ":" is greater then start time and less then end time.. and if it is return true then you can check for the digites after ":".