# What is the best way to store Zodiac Signs start and end date

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am working on an application for the iPhone in which I want to get a start and end date for a Zodiac sign to display on the label.  I am not sure how to store this info. I was thinking to store it in `Core Data` but that could be slow traversing it every time. My other idea is to have a `NSDictionary` of arrays for each sign. For example

```
self.zodiacSignsDates = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"December 22",@"January 20",nil], @"Capricorn", 
                             [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"January 21", @"February 18",nil], @"Aquarius"
                             ,nil];
```

I might also use this `NSDictionary` later on to figure out zodiac sign for a birth date.

Please let me know what you think on on how to storing such data

Thanks!

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/q/1072848/716216

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have the code on how to calculate the sign from a date.  I would like to know a good way of storing the ranges for each zodiac sign.

Comment: Well considering this is a pretty small amount of data, NSUserDefaults should do you well.

Comment: Let me give you a bigger picture if you don't mind.   I already have core data database with people in it and their birth day stored as date and zodiac sign as string.  I also have a zodiac class with class methods that return sign for date and few others.  Would it be better to have sign table that will have a relationship with people table or just have a sign stored as a string and dates stored in the zodiac class in a dictionary?  Thanks!

Comment: I think saving as strings would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as an answer, because of many comments. In addition: wouldn't it be enough to just store the last day of the period in an array the same length as the zodiacs?

```
var signs = ["Capricorn","Aquarius", ... ];
var lastDay = ["01-20", "02-18", ... ];
```

last one, i promise. if you want to keep those english strings, you could do this:
(since I assume, you already have a list of zodiacs around)

```
var dates = [["December 22","January 20"],["January 21","February 18"],[etc,etc] ];
```

and then

```
private String[] getFromTo( string zodiac ){
   var idx = signs.indexOf(zodiac);
   return dates[idx];
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I would like to have a method which returns the start and end of one zodiac signs.  I think this way would be quicker to access this info.

Comment: I am not up to date with my astrology, but you could event get away with just storing the day since there are 12 zodiacs (still, or again, right?) and writing a small method to calculate the strings, but a dictionary will do just fine as well.

Comment: Thanks again for your response! I will try to work with dictionary see where it takes me. They did find a 13th sign but i still believe in 12 :)