# iPhone iOS NSDate how to detect if a date range includes a start of a month?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate, nscalendar

I got a set of events that I'm displaying in a UITableView. Each event has a start date and and end date, with 1-3 days between them.

I'm trying to detect if a particular date range includes the start of a month (ex: August 1st), and add a special marker to that table view cell.

I've read that NSDate and calendar manipulations are expensive operations and my table view is already not the fastest in the world. **How can I efficiently determine if a date range includes a start of a month?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Check if an NSDate occurs between two other NSDates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072848/how-to-check-if-an-nsdate-occurs-between-two-other-nsdates)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, thinking pragmatically, you can check the months of each date:

```
NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDateComponents* startComp = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:startDate];

NSDateComponents* endComp = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:endDate];

if([startComp month] != [endComp month]){
    // start of month included
}
```

You can do the same for the days, and if the `endDate` day value is LESS than the `startDate` day value then you know you have a 1st in there somewhere. Obviously this way will only work properly if the events span less than a month (which you said they do).

Answer (score 3):

Check the month values of two end dates, if they are different you have a start of month otherwise you dont.

**Edit:** First check any endpoint(start or end) date day value equals 1.

Comment: Plus the case when the month is the same, but one of the dates is the first.

Comment: Maybe first check if the day value equals 1 :)

Answer (score 3):

You could check if the end date is lower than the start date.

E.g.: start = Jun 30, end = Jul 2.

```
NSDate * start, end;

NSInteger startDay = [[start descriptionWithCalendarFormat:@"%d" timeZone:nil locale:nil] intValue];
NSInteger endDay = [[start descriptionWithCalendarFormat:@"%d" timeZone:nil locale:nil] intValue];

if (endDay < startDay) {
    // bingo!
}
```

Comment: @rad the end date DAY value is higher than the start date, so this would work. :)

Comment: counter example start=june 1 end=june 3