# NSDate Comparison

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a list of birthdays. From the list of b'days, I need to select all the b'days which occurs in the next 30 days.

For example : Today's date is 07/13, then I need to list all the b'days which occurs between 07/13 and 08/13.

Is there any built in method to select the dates in this manner.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No built-in method for this, but you've got logic and docs, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Check if an NSDate occurs between two other NSDates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072848/how-to-check-if-an-nsdate-occurs-between-two-other-nsdates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NSPredicate` for this:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDate *later = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:(30*24*60*60)];
NSPredicate *pre = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF >= %@ AND SELF <= %@", now, later];
NSArray *upcomingBirthdays = [birthdays filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pre];
```

Answer (score 0):

You going to have to work the logic out for yourself, here is a link to "Date and Time Programming Guide". It contains some sample code to check if "Date" falls within a Week. Might be a good place to start.

[Apple's guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007836-SW1)

Comment: Thank you Date. I will check it out.