# Loop in a model array

Tags: objective-c

I've this model:

```
@interface Data : NSObject
@property int Period; 
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSDate *Start;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSDate *End;
@end

@implementation Data
@synthesize Period, Start, End;
@end
```

I add data in mutable array.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* myArray;
self.myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];

Data *element1 =[ [Data alloc] init];
element1.Period = 1;
element1.Start = dateStart1;
element1.End = dateEnd1;
[self.myArray addObject:element1];

Data *element2 =[ [Data alloc] init];
element2.Period = 2;
element2.Start = dateStart2;
element2.End = dateEnd2;
[self.myArray addObject:element2];

Data *element3 =[ [Data alloc] init];
element3.Period = 3;
element3.Start = dateStart3;
element3.End = dateEnd3;
[self.myArray addObject:element3];
```

I can extract Start dates from array

```
Data * extractDateStart = [self.myArray valueForKey:@"Start"];
NSLog(@"All Start Dates: %@", extractDateStart);
```

I need to cycle for that array to search in which of the three period a specific date (inserted by user) is.

I know how to extract data from 'normal' array:

```
for(NSString * extractDate in self.myArray) {
    NSLog(extractDate);
}
```

And know too how to compare one date with another:

> ```
>   switch ([dateInserted compare: date]) {
>     case NSOrderedAscending:
>         // dateInserted old than date
>       break;
>     case NSOrderedSame:
>         // dateInserted the same then date
>       break;
>     case NSOrderedDescending:
>         // dateInserted new then date 
>       break;
>     default:
>         // generic error
>       break;
> }
> ```

But how to move in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might not understand your question, but it sounds like you:

- Have a user provided `NSDate`
- Want to find the `Data` object for which the `NSDate` falls between the `Start` and `End` dates

If that's the case, something like this should work:

```
NSDate *dateToFind = ...;
Data *foundData = nil; // We will put the correct Data object here if we find it    

for (Data *data in self.myArray) {
    // Test that dateToFind is between data.Start and data.End
    if (([dateToFind compare:data.Start] != NSOrderedAscending) 
            && ([dateToFind compare:data.End] != NSOrderedDescending)))
    {
        foundData = data; // dateToFind is in this Data's date range
    }
}

// foundData is either nil or contains the Data you were looking for
```

For other good ways to test if a date falls between two other dates, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072848/how-to-check-if-an-nsdate-occurs-between-two-other-nsdates).

Comment: That helps a lot, THANKS! The 3 last problems: 1) when dateToFind is in this Data's range how to know also the data.Period ? 2) the range contains also the Start and End data (i mean if the dateToFind is == to data.Start or data.End) ? 3) What happens if dateToFind not falls at all between the Start and End dates ?

Comment: Glad to hear I could help @Fabrizio! As to your follow up: 1) The code puts the matching Data object in the variable foundData, so to get the period you would just look at foundData.Period. 2) As written, the range is strictly less then / greater then - but you can modify it using NSOrderedSame to be inclusive when the dateToFind is == to a start / end date. 3) If dateToFind does not fall in any of the data periods, then foundData will be nil - which is a common way to show failure in Objective-C. Hope these help, and please accept my answer if you feel it is a solution. Good luck!

Comment: 2) NSOrderedSame: i should simple add another two && for these 2 case, isn't it ? 3) so i should add at the end of your code an if statement for nil case, is it correct ? Sorry to ask you again but i'd like only be sure to have well understood your precious suggestions.

Comment: No worries - happy to help! I can't fit the code in the comment, but if you understand how the code above means: ((date > start) && (date < end)) then what you'll want to change it too is: (((date > start) && (date < end)) || (date == start) || (date == end)). The OR for each of the equals is important so the expression can still be true if the date is between start and end, but not equal to either of them. As for testing nil, non-nil objects evaluate to true, so you can write if(foundData) { // we found it } else { // we did not find it }. (excuse the poor formatting).