# How to check whether now date is during 9:00-18:00

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

When my app is launched I want to check whether the date is between 9:00-18:00.

And I can get the time of now using `NSDate`. How can I check the time?

Comment: To check if date is between two other dates see link:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1072993/2092007

Comment: @kshin thankyou for your link , it is a different , because it is not a certain day or month, it is "today"s 9:00-18:00

Comment: It's always between 9:00 and 18:00 today somewhere in the world. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So many answers and so many flaws...

You can use `NSDateFormatter` in order to get an user-friendly string from a date. *But* it is a **very** bad idea to use that string for date comparisons!
Please ignore any answer to your question that involves using strings...

If you want to get information about a date's year, month, day, hour, minute, etc., you should use `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents`.

In order to check whether a date is between 9:00 and 18:00 you can do the following:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:date];

if (dateComponents.hour >= 9 && dateComponents.hour < 18) {
    NSLog(@"Date is between 9:00 and 18:00.");
}
```

**EDIT:**
Whoops, using `dateComponents.hour <= 18` will result in wrong results for dates like 18:01. `dateComponents.hour < 18` is the way to go. ;)

Comment: Yes this is the best solution, however this is stackoverflow and that means it won't necessarily be accepted as such...

Comment: OMG I can't believe how Objective-C is so incredibly complicated just for a simple time comparison.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the Objective-C language.

Answer (score 6):

Construct dates for 09:00 and 18:00 today and compare the current time with those dates:

```
NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:NSEraCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:now];

[components setHour:9];
[components setMinute:0];
[components setSecond:0];
NSDate *nineHundred = [cal dateFromComponents:components];

[components setHour:18];
NSDate *eighteenHundred = [cal dateFromComponents:components];

if ([nineHundred compare:now] != NSOrderedDescending &&
    [eighteenHundred compare:now] != NSOrderedAscending)
{
    NSLog(@"Date is between 09:00 and 18:00");
}
```

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your ways, I understand what you means , but the nineHundred and eighteenHundred is nil,I think I can fix the bug, thankyou for your method

Comment: @Relex And what is the fix required?  Please update my answer as this is the best way to construct dates necessary for comparison.

Comment: Thank you! This is the only answer that's using `NSCalendar` to do the comparison. There's still hope. Constructing the two dates for the comparison isn't necessary, though. You can check if the component's `hour` property is between 9 and 18 directly. Also, the week, weekday, timezone calendar units aren't required.

Comment: @trojanfoe In some situations constructing dates for the comparison can be better, so your code isn't bad at all. But for this simple check it's a little bit overkill. ;)

Comment: Ahh, please don't remove your code! It's quite convenient when you want to check whether a date is between two absolute dates like February, 21 2013 8:32am and February, 22 2013 9:32 am or something similar.

Comment: @FabianKreiser Apparently it wasn't working though (the dates were `nil`) as I did it from the manual without testing. Can you suggest why they would be `nil`?

Comment: @trojanfoe your date is nil because you did not set the calendar , add this code [components setCalendar:cal];

Comment: @GuoLuchuan But the components were created *from* the calendar.

Comment: Or use `NSCalendar`'s `-dateFromComponents:` directly instead of `NSDateComponent`'s `-date` method. I never liked that one, anyway.

Comment: OK answer restored with all its inperfection ;-)