# How to compare time between a time interval in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

```
NSDate* firstTime = (NSDate *)openTime;//10:00AM
NSDate* secondTime = (NSDate *)closeTime;//10:00PM
NSDate* nowTime = (NSDate *)str;//3:09PM

NSComparisonResult result1 = [nowTime  compare:firstTime];
NSComparisonResult result2 = [nowTime  compare:secondTime];
if(result1==NSOrderedDescending  && result2==NSOrderedAscending)
{
    return TRUE;//------ expecting result is true as per sample
}
else
{
    return FALSE;
}
```

I am having this code and I am expecting result is true that I gave in code. but I am getting is false. My aim is to check my current time between the start time and end time. Please help me.

Comment: What are the 'date' components of your 'openTime' and 'closeTime'. Try some 'NSLog'-ing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072848/how-to-check-if-an-nsdate-occurs-between-two-other-nsdates

Comment: both "duplicate" links are linked to date&time comparsion questions - OP (seems so) wants to compare only time-components of `NSDate`

Comment: @SubinKurian: how do you really (in your code) instantiate `openTime` and `closeTime`?

Comment: no date components we have.. only time and it not getting worked at any way time coming as a string 10:00AM-10:00PM  and i am parsing it to two components and i need is compair with current time. is this current time in between this time or not

Comment: Is your openTime, closeTime really instances of NSDate? or are they strings?

Comment: NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"] autorelease]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mma"];
    NSString *str=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

Comment: Is my answer not working? If not can you share how openTime and closeTime is instantiated?

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
NSString *fromDateString = @"10:00AM";
NSString *toDateString = @"10:00PM";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mma"];
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:locale];

NSString *nowDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSDate *firstTime   = [dateFormatter dateFromString:fromDateString];
NSDate *secondTime  = [dateFormatter dateFromString:toDateString];
NSDate *nowTime     = [dateFormatter dateFromString:nowDateString];

NSComparisonResult result1 = [nowTime compare:firstTime];
NSComparisonResult result2 = [nowTime compare:secondTime];

if ((result1 == NSOrderedDescending) &&
    (result2 == NSOrderedAscending)){
    return TRUE;
}else{
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks 
I would like to know about what will be result if we campare time in 2 days.means comparing time in 2 days eg 4PM and 4AM

Answer (score 0):

I tried with some dummy data in OSX, you need to change with your original values

```
NSDate *nowTime=[NSDate date];
NSDate *firstTime=[NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:@"22 April 2013"];
NSDate *secondTime=[NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:@"23 April 2013"];


BOOL first=([nowTime compare:firstTime] == NSOrderedDescending);//now time is more then firsttime
BOOL second=([nowTime compare:secondTime] == NSOrderedAscending);//now time is more then secondtime
if(first && second){
    ;//return YES;
    NSLog(@"Between");
}
else{
    ;//return NO;
    NSLog(@"Not in Between");
}
```

EDIT:

I checked it with time as:

```
NSDate *firstTime=[NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:@"5PM"];
NSDate *secondTime=[NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:@"10PM"];
```

And it is working good.

Comment: we tried it , 1st part is ok (First) second giving is NO it is wrong. what we will do?

Comment: check the time is it really in the range...

Comment: yes.. now time is 3:37 PM and i am comparing with 10:00AM and 10:00PM

Comment: can u check it with a time? can u use 10:00AM and 10:00PM as time insted of 22 April 2013 & 23 April 2013. it true in date case i think but in time it not getting true

Comment: @SubinKurian: I checked it with time, and it worked. You can also try the above code

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
  NSString *openTime = @"10:00 AM";
    NSString *closeTime = @"10:00 PM";
    NSString *str = @"11:09 PM";

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mma"];

    NSDate *firstTime =  [[NSDate alloc]init];
    firstTime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:openTime];

    NSDate* secondTime =  [[NSDate alloc]init];
    secondTime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:closeTime];
    NSDate* nowTime =  [[NSDate alloc]init];
    nowTime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:str];

    NSTimeInterval interval =[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSLog(@"interval : %f",interval);

    if([nowTime timeIntervalSince1970] >= [firstTime timeIntervalSince1970] && [nowTime timeIntervalSince1970] <= [secondTime timeIntervalSince1970])
    {

       return YES;// Between Interval

    }
    else
   {
   return NO; // Not between Interval
    }
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: it not working anyway. it is false

Comment: @Subin I have updated my answer. Check it

Answer (score 0):

Convert your dates to timeInterval, like:

```
NSDate* firstTime = (NSDate *)openTime;//10:00AM
NSDate* secondTime = (NSDate *)closeTime;//10:00PM
NSDate* nowTime = (NSDate *)str;//3:09PM
NSTimeInterval firstTimeInterVal = [firstTime NSTimeIntervalSince1970]
NSTimeInterval secondTimeInterVal = [secondTime NSTimeIntervalSince1970]
NSTimeInterval nowTimeInterval = [nowTime NSTimeIntervalSince1970];
```

Then compare like:

```
if (nowTimeInterval > firstTimeInterVal && nowTimeInterval < secondTimeInterVal) {
    /**Between**/
}else{
    /**Not Between**/
}
```