# How to check current date between two dates in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsdate

I have two dates, starting date and ending date. Now i want to check whether my current date is in between these two dates.

e.g. start date:  2013-09-17 15:05:00 +0000
end date: 013-09-25 17:05:00 +0000

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Check if an NSDate occurs between two other NSDates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072848/how-to-check-if-an-nsdate-occurs-between-two-other-nsdates)

Answer (score 2):

```
NSComparisonResult result,restult2; 
//has three possible values: NSOrderedSame,NSOrderedDescending, NSOrderedAscending

result = [currentDate compare:startDate]; // comparing two dates
result2 = [currentDate compare:endDate]; // comparing two dates

if(result==NSOrderedAscending && result==NSOrderedDescending)
{

NSLog(@"Between the StartDate and Enddate");

}
```

Comment: If you want to take care of your ressources, calculate `result`, then do the `if(result==NSOrderedAscending)` and do `result2=...`. Otherwise `result2` is always calculated even if not needed. This may waste a few cycles.

Answer (score 0):

Here us a method i wrote:

```
- (NSInteger)daysBetweenDate:(NSDate*)fromDateTime andDate:(NSDate*)toDateTime {
    NSDate *fromDate;
    NSDate *toDate;
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    [calendar rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit startDate:&fromDate
                 interval:NULL forDate:fromDateTime];
    [calendar rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit startDate:&toDate
                 interval:NULL forDate:toDateTime];
    NSDateComponents *differenceComponents = [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                                         fromDate:fromDate
                                                          toDate:toDate
                                                         options:0];
    return [differenceComponents day];
}
```

It calculates the number of days between 2 dates. You can use it to calculate the interval and then use it again to calculate if the third date(the one you want to check) is in the interval you are interested in.

Comment: i just want to check whether my current date is in between or not

Comment: You can do so, by using this method and 2nd grade math skills.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter *formate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formate setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];--> this line first set type of formate to compare
NSDate *date1 = [formate dateFromString:@"1-5-2010"];-->first date
NSDate *date2 = [formate dateFromString:@"7-5-2010"];-->second date
//difference between dates in miliseconds
NSTimeInterval interval = [date1 timeIntervalSinceDate:date2];

//compare two dates 
NSComparisonResult result = [date1 compare:date2];
switch (result)
{
    case NSOrderedAscending: NSLog(@"%@ is greater than %@", date2, date1); break;
    case NSOrderedDescending: NSLog(@"%@ is less %@", date2, date1); break;
    case NSOrderedSame: NSLog(@"%@ is equal to %@", date2, date1); break;
    default: NSLog(@"erorr dates %@, %@", date2, date1); break;
}
```