# NSDate between two dates

Tags: ios, nsdate

Is this a good way to check if serverOnNowDate is between publishedStartTime  and  publishedEndTime?

```
 return !( [self.publishedStartTime compare:serverOnNowDate] == NSOrderedDescending
        || [self.publishedEndTime compare:serverOnNowDate] == NSOrderedAscending );
```

Comment: If exactly between then `&&`

Comment: what is the problem you are facing. Your code works fine

Comment: this is used to check an array of 1000 objects for objects who's start /end date includes the serverTime... No objects are found , but I know for sure that some of them should return YES in this method

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Check if an NSDate occurs between two other NSDates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072848/how-to-check-if-an-nsdate-occurs-between-two-other-nsdates)

Answer (score 6):

Written as a instance method:

```
- (BOOL)isBetweenDate:(NSDate *)earlierDate andDate:(NSDate *)laterDate
{
    // first check that we are later than the earlierDate.
    if ([self compare:earlierDate] == NSOrderedDescending) {

        // next check that we are earlier than the laterData
        if ( [self compare:laterDate] == NSOrderedAscending ) {
            return YES;
        }
    }

    // otherwise we are not
    return NO;
}
```

Usage:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate now];

if ( [date isBetween:startDate andDate:finishDate] ) {
    NSLog(@"Between dates!!!");
}
```

Comment: A shorter form: 
```return [self compare:earlierDate] == NSOrderedDescending && [self compare:laterDate] == NSOrderedAscending;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below method

```
- (BOOL)inputDate:(NSDate*)date start:(NSDate*)beginDate end:(NSDate*)endDate
{
    if ([date compare:beginDate] == NSOrderedAscending)
        return NO;

    if ([date compare:endDate] == NSOrderedDescending) 
        return NO;

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: this should either be a class method, or you don't need 3 parameters because you can use self.