# If statement between two times of day

Tags: objective-c, ios7, time

What is the easiest way to have an `if` statement between two times? For example:

```
if ([timeisBetween=1:00 and 8:40]) {
    NSLog(@"Inside time period");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Not in time period - after 8:30 in the morning")
}
```

and

```
if ([timeisBetween=22:00 and 5:40]) {
    NSLog(@"Inside time period 10:00 at night to 5:40 in the morning");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Not in time period");
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What data do you have and what is its type (`NSDate`, `NSTimeInterval`, `NSString`)?

Comment: There are several ways to do it, but they all require actual programming, if you want a reasonably general solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Check if an NSDate occurs between two other NSDates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072848/how-to-check-if-an-nsdate-occurs-between-two-other-nsdates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your NSStrings to NSDates via a NSDateFormatter and then compare them. Make sure your NSDate is between those ranges. These snippets will help point you in the right direction.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *startDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"2014-17-03 6:45:58"];
NSDate *endDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"2014-17-03 8:45:58"];

if ([startDate compare: endDate] == NSOrderedDescending) {
    NSLog(@"start is later than end");

} else if ([startDate compare:endDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    NSLog(@"start is earlier than end");

} else {
    NSLog(@"Same Dates");

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do I do with times of everyday, rather than a set date?? Thanks,