# Make background image change based on time of day (Local time)

Tags: ios, background, localtime

Im making an app using Xcode5 and i want to have the background image (or Image View) of one of my View Controllers change between a set of images based on the local time

pretty much have a certain image show between

0600am - 1159am image1

1200pm - 1759pm image2

1800pm - 2359pm image3

0000am - 0559am image4.

Its my first time coding and i cant find anything on this matter so if someone can help me or walk me through it I would really appreciate it! 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this: [How to Check if an NSDate occurs between two other NSDates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072848/how-to-check-if-an-nsdate-occurs-between-two-other-nsdates) to check your date ranges then call a method based on the results to change your background image to the correct one.  Post some code if you are having trouble.

Comment: Thanks. But like i said its my first time coding and im learning everything online so How would i implement that into what i want to do?

I know i need an "If then" statement but i dont know how to write it up. where would i put it as well? sorry for the stupid questions. thanks!