# Checking if string time range is now

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch

I have an object with 2 `String` properties: `notifyFrom` and `notifyTo`.

They are like:

`notifyFrom`: `14:00`

`notifyTo`: `18:00`

and before I send the user a notification (that's part of my app) I want to check if the time is between those hours and just if it is to send the notification.

**Note**: Date doesn't matter here. I just want to check the times

What is the best way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: means do you want to check that whether your time string is between `notifyfrom` and `notifyto` ?? If this is so then what about date ?? or date doesn't matter ??

Comment: @Lion Date doesn't matter here. I just want to check the times

Comment: Get the `hour` component from the current date and check if the `Range`  `notifyFrom...notifyTo` `contains` the value. However it becomes a bit more complicated if `To` can be lower than `From`

Answer (score 0):

You can write method something like,

```
+ (BOOL)date:(NSDate*)date isBetweenDate:(NSDate*)beginDate andDate:(NSDate*)endDate
{
if ([date compare:beginDate] == NSOrderedAscending)
    return NO;

if ([date compare:endDate] == NSOrderedDescending)
    return NO;

return YES;
}
```

Reference : [this so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072848/how-to-check-if-an-nsdate-occurs-between-two-other-nsdates)

Answer (score 0):

First of all convert the input two strings to dates

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:notifyFrom];
NSDate *date2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:notifyTo];

NSDate *userDate = [NSDate date];

if (([userDate laterDate: date1] == userDate) && ([userDate laterDate: date2] == date2)){
}
```