# How to Check Between Two Dates in a Month?

Tags: javascript, date

How do I go about checking between two dates in a current month?

For example, I want to check between the 1st of January and the 8th of January regardless of year (I'm British so my dates are (dd/mm/yyyy):

```
var date = new Date(); //This is the current date

date1 = new Date('01, 01, date.getFullYear()');
date2 = new Date('08, 01, date.getFullYear()');

if(date >= date1 && date <= date2) {
// Do Something
} else {
// Don't do something
}
```

Or another example, let's say Halloween:

```
var date = new Date();

date1 = new Date('31, date.getMonth(), date.getFullYear()');

if(date == date1) {
// Do Something
} else {
// Don't do something
}
```

I'm not quite sure how to format it in Javascript, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That doesn't even seem like correct syntax.

Comment: That's why I asked the question

Comment: Not even clear what *"check between two dates"*  means. Provide a proper explanation of what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Done @charlietfl

Comment: Still not very clear. What is input for this and what are expected results? See [mcve]

Comment: Okay, so let's say today is between the 1st of January and the 8th of January I will change the <h1> tag on my page to say something. I already know how to change it but don't know about date checking.

Comment: Not hard to research how to get the date of month and current month from javascript date object. Then compare those values to your boundary values

Comment: Please familiarize yourself [with the basics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) before asking a question.

Comment: @charlietfl I already tried doing this for the past 30 minutes or so and I am still confused that's why I came here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points...

- `new Date` parameters are (year, month, day) regardless of your local settings.
- The single quotes around the parameters aren't correct syntax.
- Months in JavaScript are zero-indexed, so January is zero.

So your `date2` should be `date2 = new Date(date.getFullYear(), 0, 8)`.

Also get in the habit of putting `var` in front of variable declarations. Don't worry why just yet; you'll learn about that as you go.

So your code should go something like this:

```
var date = new Date();

var date1 = new Date(date.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
var date2 = new Date(date.getFullYear(), 0, 8);

if(date >= date1 && date <= date2) {
    // this part was correct :)
    //Do Something
}
```

Comment: I don't suppose there would be a way of making this work on iOS? I recently found out they use a different way of displaying the date on iOS

Comment: Sorry @Ryan, I'm pretty feeble with iOS. If you're using JavaScript anywhere (including iOS) then it should be the same. If you're using Objective C then [maybe this will help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1072993/2091410)? Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You are initializing your [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) objects incorrectly. If you want to initialize a date with a string, that string needs to have a format that can be processed by [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

The string you are passing, however, looks like you actually don't want to pass any strings at all. So just omit the single quotes, like this:

```
var date1 = new Date(date.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
```

Note that the first argument is the year, the second is the month (zero-based, so 0 is January) and the third is the day of the month.