# Need to check if the current time interval lies between start and end time in objective c

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsdate

I want to know whether the current time is present between the start time and the enter, both (start-time and  end-time) are static. Something like this suppose my current time is 10:15 AM the start time is 9:15AM and End time is 11:00 AM. So this should be the function should return me A BOOL value that is in this case is yes, now suppose my current time is 12:00 AM then the function should return me a bool value NO. So I am in confusion about how to create such a function (method) which will do the above trick. Note the start time and end time will be for the same day.

Comment: find the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947947/how-to-determine-if-an-nstimeinterval-occurred-during-an-arbitrary-nsdate)

Comment: Hi @Mrugen,Have you find the way to short out this ? thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSDate has all the functions you need to do this.  Check out the documentation.

Comment: I searched a lot but could not find one it would be great if you can tell me about that function or some link would help .I really need that as teh application is in the final phase and only this thing is left .It would be really great if you can help me(fast).

Comment: You can find extensive and very helpful documentation on all Apple functions by going to Organizer in xCode and clicking on the Documentation button. Search there for NSDate.

Comment: Use the compare: function and compare the sample date with the start date and the end date.

Comment: Feel free to give the answer an up vote and accept if you think it deserves it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  NSDate * now = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

  //current time
    NSString *currentTimeString = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:now];
    NSDate *dateCurrent = [outputFormatter dateFromString:currentTimeString];


    NSString *timeStart = @"09:00:00";
    NSString *timeEnd = @"22:00:00";

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

    NSDate *dateStart= [formatter timeStart];
    NSDate *dateEnd = [formatter timeEnd];
    NSComparisonResult result = [dateCurrent compare:dateStart];
    NSComparisonResult resultSecond = [date2 compare:dateEnd];

  if(result == NSOrderedDescending && resultSecond == NSOrderedDescending)
    {
        NSLog(@"current time lies in starting and end time");

}else {
        NSLog(@"current time don't lie in starting and end time");

    }
```